# Google Cloud Logging filter to remove duplicates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

Dues to the distributed nature of my system, I have duplicates in my Google Cloud Loggings logs.

```
03:34pm : id: 2094380, message 1
03:34pm : id: 2094380, message 1
03:35pm : id: 5922284, message 2
03:35pm : id: 5922284, message 2
```

My end goal is to create a graph based on a count of my events (using a log-based metrics).
Is there a way to filter in Google Cloud Logging my logs to have only the first occurrence of each line?

Comment: I'd be inclined to sink your log records to BigQuery and then run SQL over your results to produce your desired output.

Comment: Use log analytics to query your logs with BigQuery and therefore use the analytics functions that you want (i.e. use window to remove duplicates (and on fields that mean "duplicate") over a period of time): https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/log-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Like what `koblan` and `guillaume blaquiere` suggested, we can store the logs generated to a big query table follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) to export your logs to bigquery and use distinct functionality for getting distinct results. Now as `guillaume blaquiere` said query them in log analytics or [looker studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-looker-studio) for visualizing your log data.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the full LogEntry that is written then specifying the `insertId` would de-duplicate them (assuming the timestamp is the same).

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry